# Static geometry problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, free-body-diagram, statics

Why is the force Nb has triangle of height a and base 2r. Why is not height 2r and base a?

[image]

Comment: Before you resolve a force into components, you need to have a well-defined coordinate system. And there is also no physics question here.

Comment: Agree, this is a math/geometry question. You form two similar triangles to find the angle of $N_B$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The dimensions are switched because the force $N_B$ is perpendicular to the plate. When making a line perpendicular to another line in 2 dimensions, if $dy/dx=s$ for the original line, $dy/dx=-1/s$ for the perpendicular line.